# "For a second time" or "For the second time"

Tags: word-choice, articles, definite-article, indefinite-article

What would be the correct sentence from the below two:

1. **For a** second time, in a few months we decided to meet.

OR

2. **For the** second time, in a few months we decided to meet.

Is one of the two incorrect or can they be used interchangeably?

Comment: It doesn't matter which article you use, but do you mean that they decided _then_ to meet a few months later, or that the decision to meet was made a few months later?

Comment: @KateBunting has the logical sense: For the second time in a few months, we decided to meet.

Comment: What's the intended meaning? Did you decide to meet in a few months, and this would be your second meeting? Or did you decide to meet for the second time, and the first time had been just a few months before?

Comment: @KateBunting, thanks for the comment, the intended meaning was "that the decision to meet was made a few months later"...I have selected the answer below but if you have a different answer or an explanation I am still curious to know.

Comment: "A few months later, we decided to meet for a second time" (or "decided for a second time that we should meet"). It's putting the two phrases together that makes your version confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, use **a/an** when you're referring to one thing out of many similar things, and **the** when you're referring to a specific thing. In your example, you can use either article. There's a very slight difference between them, but it doesn't have a substantial effect on the meaning.

> For a second time.....

This suggests there might be other similar second times, or perhaps a third, fourth and fifth time. A second time is one out of many similar times.

> For the second time....

There is only one second time, and this is it.

Comment: Thank you for answering this. It clears things up a bit for me.

Answer (score 0):

My take on it (disregarding the actual meaning of the example sentences) is that *for a second time* just means 'again (after one previous occasion)'.

*For the second time* implies that the speaker knows from a future perspective how many times altogether the event happened, and that this was the second of them.